# SQL pass Windows Auth details using Server Authentication

Tags: sql

We have a MSSQL2005 Database on our domain, We can only connect to the database using Windows Authentication. When i am on the domain it connects perfectly, but when i am not on the domain i am unable to pass through my domain credentials to connect to the database.

I tried using Server Authentication and passing domain credentials but i haven't been successful

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/02/26/using-windows-authentication-from-a-non-domain-joined-machine.aspx) he gives a nice explanation including screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is even possible? You want to connect to database using domain account when your windows machine is not on a domain.

Try using local windows account.